# Getting error in Karate v1.1.0 - TypeError: invokeMember (contains) on ["ABC","XYZ","OTHR","NEW"] failed due to: Message not supported

Tags: karate

I was using Karate v0.9.6 all this while. Recently thought of upgrading the version to 1.1.0 and then 1.2.0.

One thing is troubling a lot is as belows,

Earlier I used to use 'contains' to verify in the schema that

#An array of expected values

- def dept_type_code = ["ABC","XYZ","OTHR","NEW"]

##Then verify in the schema that the type_code has any one of those values in the array

- def index_department_type_schema = {"code": '#? dept_type_code.contains(_)'}

It was working in 0.9.6 but with 1.1.0 is failing with error;
**TypeError: invokeMember (contains) on ["ABC","XYZ","OTHR","NEW"] failed due to: Message not supported.**

I'm sure I'm missing important part from the release notes. I would really appreciate any solution to this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

replacing .contains with .includes resolved the issue

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#java-api-s-for-maps-and-lists-are-no-longer-visible-within-js-blocks